# Firebase: Uploading an image through html input and storing it as a property of an object

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

For learning purposes I decided to make a simple closet imitation website where I could basically add new clothes as objects and store them into firebase database. Where am I currently: I successfully managed to make a registration and login option for the website. When registering, an object of a person, with properties email, full name, encrypted password and username is stored into Realtime Database. After that I managed to make a simple "Add Item" form, where you can fill in name of the item, choose a category from a select input and also upload your own image of an item. After every added item, the item gets stored into Realtime Database into the current's username that is logged in. The current username now gets an extra property "Items" which now stores all the added objects/items. The last thing I managed was to display the items on the screen by using "get", looping through "Items" and dynamically creating a new div with p for name, p for category, and an img for image. So basically I create a new div for every item in database and then I append it to my website.

Now at the time I realized that for uploading images you actually need to use Firebase Storage, so I decided that instead of uploading an image, I will select image through input, get it's URL (*URL.createObjectURL*) and store that URL as a property inside of the item/object. Now reading the data and displaying the image works fine when adding new items and displaying them, but after closing the browser and opening it again, items display without an image. In the Firefox console I get the following error: *Security Error: Content at http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html may not load data from blob:http://127.0.0.1:5500/e324b58c-97ab-4ba4-b5e9-357dc9b06d92.*

Now I realized that this option is not going to work for me due to safety reasons. I decided to store images locally, because I only wanted to learn working with objects and saving them into database. I would really like to understand how can I store an item/object with name, category and image as a properties, into a Firebase database and then retrieve data and display them. My only problem currently is for images, so how can I upload images of different items/objects, store them into database and then retrieve them as object properties.

I would like to say that I'm currently learning so I may use some wrong word terminology regarding programming. Thank you in advance.

Currently I am stuck, so I'm thinking about instead of uploading the images I will just use the images from the web.

Comment: Firebase storage can generate public URLs which you can then store in your database as a property of an object

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Thank you so much. I did some research and I managed to upload images to Firebase storage and then save the URL as a property into an object in Realtime Database. Thank you again!